# IE Automation with Powershell - Selecting multiple items in a listbox

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do some automation on IE with Powershell.

On the webpage I have a listbox that allows multiple values to be selected, I would like to be able to select all of the items within the listbox, but cannot figure out how to do it.

I use this code to get an object with the listbox.

`$groupings = $doc.getElementByID("ctl00_pageContent_lstGrouping")`

I have figured out that I can return the selected status of each of the options by using this code

`($groupings | where {$_.tagName -eq "OPTION"}).selected`

I thought it would then a case of setting the selected property to $true, but I get an error returned

`PS C:\Windows\system32> ($groupings | where {$_.tagName -eq "OPTION"}).selected = $true

Property 'selected' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:1
+ ($groupings | where {$_.tagName -eq "OPTION"}).selected = $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException`

I'm assuming the property is read-only hence the error.